# FluentValidation, Multiple conditions not working in one rule

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

These are my rules:

```
public class CambiarPasswordViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<CambiarPasswordViewModel>
{
    public CambiarPasswordViewModelValidator(
        IStringLocalizer<CambiarPasswordViewModelValidator> localizer,
        IStringLocalizer<SharedLocalizer> sharedLocalizer)
    {
        RuleFor(c => c.ContraseñaActual)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage(sharedLocalizer["Requerido *"]);
        RuleFor(c => c.ContraseñaNueva)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage(sharedLocalizer["Requerido *"])
            .Equal(c => c.ContraseñaConfirmacion)
                .When(c => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.ContraseñaNueva))
                .WithMessage(localizer["Nueva Contraseña y Confirmación no concuerdan"]);
        RuleFor(c => c.ContraseñaConfirmacion)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage(sharedLocalizer["Requerido *"]);
    }
}
```

My problem is second rule is not working as expected. I need ContraseñaNueva validates when empty and also when value not equal to ContraseñaConfirmacion, however, only empty validation is injected to input in razor page. If I change the order, Equal validation works but NotEmpty doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

it will be enough to separate the rules,

```
RuleFor(c => c.ContraseñaNueva)
    .NotEmpty().WithMessage(sharedLocalizer["Requerido *"]);

RuleFor(c => c.ContraseñaNueva)
    .Equal(c => c.ContraseñaConfirmacion)
    .When(c => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.ContraseñaNueva))
    .WithMessage(localizer["Nueva Contraseña y Confirmación no concuerdan"]);
```

Comment: levent, doing so it only added the first rule, so when I check in ModelState for errors, only shows me the message 'Requerido *': <div class="ffl-wrapper">
                        <label class="ffl-label" for="Contrase_aNueva">Contraseña Nueva *</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="password" data-val="true" data-val-required="Requerido *" id="Contrase_aNueva" name="ContraseñaNueva">
                        <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ContraseñaNueva" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>

Comment: I noticed fluent validation has issues injecting multiple conditions on one rule into the razor page inputs' attributes instead of using data annotation that put all rules. My project is asp.net core MVC (not web api).

Comment: @AldemarCuartasCarvajal: levent's solution should work given the requirements stated in your question. You need to split those rules into two different calls to `RuleFor` and use the `When` method on the second rule, so it only executes when `ContraseñaNueva` has a value.